# My superior has been giving gifts to only one employee

Tags: gifts

I have an awkward situation at my workplace. My male superior is very friendly to one of the female employees and of late I have observed that he has given two holiday gifts only to her like a box of chocolates and also another item she likes since she keeps talking about that subject a lot.

On top of it there is an appearance of favoritism in this case since the person was hired for a junior role and within 2-3 months she has been kind of given better duties whichs is more like a promotion. And at the same time, there are 2-3 more experienced folks who just mind their work and not necessarily super close to the superior and they are given different duties which are somewhat subpar meaning kind of demotion.

The fact that he has given exclusive gifts only to her, does this amount to unhealthy favoritism ? Do other employees who feel affected by it have sufficient grounds to complain to the HR? In such cases how to make sure there is no retribution?

Comment: If those other employees “just mind their work” why do you assune they are ready to complain?

Comment: To answer your questions: Maybe, Maybe, it's very difficult. It's worth asking yourself "What are you trying to achieve here?". Personally, I'd say unless the situation is directly negatively affecting you, you are better off staying out of it.

Comment: Depending on your actions, you might not get invited to their wedding next year. On the other hand, she might ask you to be a witness about sexual harassment. You don’t know, so wait. See what happens. If he pays for presents out of his own pocket then it’s a present, not favouritism.

Comment: *she has been kind of given better duties* Has she been given a commensurate raise or bonus?

Comment: @SolarMike I meant in the context, they are not personally overly friendly with the superior as she is

Comment: @Kaz, why don't you write that as an *answer*?  Comments are for clarifying the question, not for answering it.

Answer (score 3):

> On top of it there is an appearance of favoritism in this case since the person was hired for a junior role and within 2-3 months she has been kind of given better duties which is more like a promotion.

It could also be that she just did an excellent job and was more motivated than the other employees.

Comment: This doesn't address the gift-giving though. While one might argue that it's not OP's business it could also be argued that favouritism affects OP's prospects at the company.

Comment: @jcm Why doesn't it affect the gift-giving? Sometimes companies or bosses give presents to show that the employee was going beyond his/her duties....

Answer (score 2):

> ...she has been kind of given better duties whichs is more like a promotion

You don't know why this has happened. Yes, it could be favouritism however it could equally be that she performing at a high level and it was felt she could tackle more complex tasks. Alternatively, maybe she was career-driven enough to approach your manager and *ask* for the opportunity to take on some extra responsibility.

> ...does this amount to unhealthy favoritism?

Maybe it is - only your manager really knows for sure. Since it will be almost impossible  to *prove*, I don't see how complaining to HR will achieve anything. Your manager needs to make the decisions he thinks best for the team and the organisation. If he says that, in his opinion, she was the best person for the job (for whatever reason) that's likely to be all that matters in any dispute. If *his* superiors perceive inappropriate favouritism, then it becomes a serious issue. When it comes from one of her peers, it's likely to look like nothing more than jealousy or resentment.

It's not worth it. Let this go and focus on your own career. Figure out a way you can prove your ability/enthusiasm/drive to your manager and *earn* that extra responsibility. Also, consider having a career discussion with your manager.

- Set out the career path you'd like to follow and how you want to progress within the organisation.
- Ask what you need to do (or what they need to see from you) for that to happen.
- Agree goals and metrics to measure your progress  (google "SMART goals")
- Arrange regular follow ups to review your progress
- Get your head down and deliver on the plan.

Answer (score 1):

Favouritism in this situation sounds perfectly legal (check for your location), and your superiors prerogative. However, favouritism is never good, it's a sign of bad management which leads to a very toxic culture of back-stabbing and aggrieved employees.

Maybe this person did more than you are aware of, and complaining could label you as a trouble maker. If you make a complaint to HR you should not fear retribution. In most places that is illegal.

I would be tempted to talk to HR (or even your superior), but not make a formal complaint. Just explain that it looks like favouritism and is affecting moral.

It is likely you aren't the only one that feels hard done by, so raising the issue could help your superior correct things to avoid a toxic culture.

Generally I agree with the other reply, instead of making a complaint about it, focus on yourself and your own career progression.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have said, you have no reason or proof that your supervisor is doing this for any reason other than appreciation for this employee, and so you have no leg to stand on if you try to make a formal complaint of favouratism or anything like that.  So don't do that.

You might want to mention the situation to HR and/or to your boss's boss and let them know it is affecting your morale though (and the morale of others, with respect to the other experienced people on your team you mentioned, although you should get their direct approval before involving them in any action you pursue, no matter how small it is).  They would probably like to know about this, as it is a warning sign of potential problematic favouratism that they, whose responsibility it is to keep an eye on this sort of thing, can then keep an eye on.  Don't make it an issue of favouratism, or potential misconduct, or gossip though; be very careful to centre the discussion around your personal feelings towards what you are seeing.  You don't want to come off as accusatory towards your boss (or anyone else), and you want to let them know what's in it for them to look into it; "my boss is playing favourites" is like, "ok so what?", but "I'm feeling low morale and so are the 3 other most productive team members" means "we're about to lose a bunch of our most productive workforce over this and have to spend company resources replacing those people", and that's way more convincing.